# Any way to remove X button from chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to modify chrome tabs to remove the button that closes the tab?

I've read through [chrome develope tab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html). but I don't see any mention of the close button.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Not possible** at the moment without forking the whole chromium project. See [bug report #50913](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50913) (Status: `WontFix`).

Possible workarounds:

1. If you right click on a tab you can `Pin Tab`. This will remove the close button but you can still close it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. Unfortunately, this will also remove the window title.
2. The close button is removed if the width of the tab gets very small.

Have a look at the same question on SuperUser: [*How to disable the close (X) button on Google Chrome tabs?*](https://superuser.com/questions/199384/how-to-disable-the-close-x-button-on-google-chrome-tabs).

Maybe you like to look at the [source code](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home) of Chromium and fix this? I think you have to start [here: `tab.cc`](https://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/tabs/tab.cc&l=1567).

Comment: If you like to have this feature open the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50913) and click on the star. Top left beside "Issue 50913".

Comment: This is one of the major reasons I won't use Chrome as my major browser.  Close-button-per-tab is an awful UI decision and I regularly accidentally close tabs and all Google have is "sod off, we can't be bothered to change it."  This is the risk of losing a customizable interface like Pale Moon's, people.

Comment: Same here. Chrome dev tools is an excellent product, but Chrome as browser is completely terrible and even as slow as it is (compared to Chrome) Firefox beats it any day.

Comment: Actually even developer tools in FF seem more user friendly for me, just the lack of speed makes me struggle every day trying to force different chromium forks to work properly, without success unfortunately

Comment: Pinning the tab also moves it all the way to left instead of leaving it right where it was.

Comment: Just to mention it: Vivaldi has that feature. Total breeze to use, i only close tabs with middleclick there

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:** The fix below only worked between Chrome version 69 and 71.

It IS possible now for inactive tabs!

I have had lots of problems while trying to switch tab while having 10-15 of them opened, accidentally closing some important tab with lots of text typed which isn't recovered by Ctrl+Shift+T

Here how to do that:

1) Open the Google Chrome browser and type the following text into the address bar:

```
chrome://flags/#close-buttons-inactive-tabs
```

This will open the flags page directly with the relevant setting.

2) Set the option named Close buttons on inactive tabs. Set it to Disabled using the drop down list next to the flag's name.

[image: 2]

3) Restart Google Chrome by closing it manually or you can also use the Relaunch button which will appear at the very bottom of the page.

[image: 3]

4) The close buttons will disappear from inactive tabs.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

That's it!

Source - https://winaero.com/blog/remove-close-buttons-inactive-tabs-google-chrome/

Comment: Does not seem to work with Chrome 71 / Linux anymore ;-(

Comment: This feature has been removed for good: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1235310

Comment: This was the perfect solution. Too bad they removed it 

Answer (score 4):

There are now Chromium-based alternative browsers which offer this - I really like [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), where not showing the X button is just one of many customization options. Also, because it is Chromium based you can install and use any Chrome extensions. It is perfect if you have many tabs open and need more of the power-user type options.